# How to dynamically add a point to a series in highcharts with rCharts

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am trying to dynamically add a data point with `highcharts` in the `rCharts` package. My problem is that I can't get the additional point to plot. I receive no error message. My data is being called from the Google Analytics Real-Time API.

My code is

```
#My initial plot here works fine   

a <- hPlot(active.users ~ timestamp, data = realDataFrame,
           type = 'spline', title = 'SBK Users per Minute', subtitle = 'Real-Time')
a$global(useUTC = TRUE)
a$xAxis(type='datetime',labels = list(format = '{value:%H:%M}'))
a$yAxis(floor = 0, gridLineColor = '#ffffff')
a

# Attempt to add point with while loop

while(TRUE){
  Sys.sleep(3)
  print(realDataAdd <- get_realtime(id, metrics = 'rt:activeUsers',
                                    filters = 'rt:pagePath=@www.mybiz.com/url/'))
  print(timestamp <-as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000)
  print(realDataAdd <- cbind(realDataAdd, timestamp))
  print(realDataAdd <- as.vector(realDataAdd, mode = 'numeric' ))
  print(a$series(addPoint = realDataAdd ,list(redraw = TRUE, shift = FALSE)))
}
```

Any help would be grand. I have also tried converting the `realDataAdd` dataframe to a vector to see if this works, but to no avail.